# Web Scraping - Python; Writing to a CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

I am trying to write data from a website. The data is listed as a table in HTML with the tags '' listing when a new block of data is listed in the rankings and '' for each descriptive item about the element in the ranking. The list is a rank of top 500 computers, listed 1-100 with each 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. item listed by '' and the each characteristic of the computer listed as '' (it's storage, max power, etc).

Here is my code:

```
# read the data from a URL
url = requests.get("https://www.top500.org/list/2018/06/")
url.status_code
url.content


# parse the URL using Beauriful Soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

filename = "computerRank10.csv"
f = open(filename,"w")

headers = "Rank, Site, System, Cores, RMax, RPeak, Power\n"
f.write(headers)

for record in soup.findAll('tr'):
# start building the record with an empty string
  tbltxt = ""
  tbltxt = tbltxt + data.text + ";"
  tbltxt = tbltxt.replace('\n', ' ')
  tbltxt = tbltxt.replace(',', '')
#    f.write(tbltxt[0:-1] + '\n')
f.write(tbltxt + '\n')

f.close()
```

I'm getting nothing and my CSV file is always blank

Comment: I think you should share with us your full code, for instance we cannot guess what's `record` variable is.

Comment: I edited the code to get rid of the record variable that was undefined. When I run that program now, I get the headers correctly written in the CSV file but now each row reads "3615" and it is just in the first column for 100 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `csv` module on the Python standard library.

Here is a simpler solution:

```
import requests
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

url = requests.get("https://www.top500.org/list/2018/06")
soup = bs(url.content, 'html.parser')

filename = "computerRank10.csv"
csv_writer = csv.writer(open(filename, 'w'))


for tr in soup.find_all("tr"):
    data = []
    # for headers ( entered only once - the first time - )
    for th in tr.find_all("th"):
        data.append(th.text)
    if data:
        print("Inserting headers : {}".format(','.join(data)))
        csv_writer.writerow(data)
        continue

    for td in tr.find_all("td"):
        if td.a:
            data.append(td.a.text.strip())
        else:
            data.append(td.text.strip())
    if data:
        print("Inserting data: {}".format(','.join(data)))
        csv_writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: I'm getting an Ascii error when I try to run this code. I don't know how to encode as string. 

The error message is below: 
    print("Inserting data: {}".format(','.join(data)))

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf6' in position 11: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You can get rid of that print statement, It was just for informing and anyways It isn't for this topic.

Comment: Or you can just encode to `utf-8` that string format like this: 
    `print("Inserting data: {}".format(','.join(data).encode('utf-8')))`

Answer (score 2):

Try the below script. It should fetch you all the data across and write the same in a csv file:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.top500.org/list/2018/06/?page={}"

def get_data(link):
    for url in [link.format(page) for page in range(1,6)]:
        res = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")

        for items in soup.select("table.table tr"):
            td = [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in items.select("th,td")]
            writer.writerow(td)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with open("tabularitem.csv","w",newline="") as infile: #if encoding issue comes up then replace with ('tabularitem.csv', 'w', newline="", encoding="utf-8")
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        get_data(link)
```